# Is there a way of adding the document's ID to the document itself upon its creation on Firestore?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

In my local model, I do carry the document's Firestore's ID, however that's something I know how to get only after the document's creation. So currently, I have to also manage a version of the model where the ID might not be there or might be optional.

I know, though, that, for example, there's a way of preemptively adding the server timestamp from the client to Firestore:

```dart
await collection.add({
  'timeOfCreation': Fieldvalue.serverTimestamp()
});
```

And I know there's a thing called `FieldPath`. However, this seems to **not** be working:

```dart
await collection.add({
  'timeOfCreation': Fieldvalue.serverTimestamp(),
  'id': FieldPath.documentId
});
```

(And neither is `FieldPath.document()`, it's a property after all...)

Is there a way of doing this currently on Firestore? (If not, why not?!)

Comment: You can create a DocReference first and add it's ID in the data as in the linked answer. Firebase [documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67641971/13130697) also has an example that creates reference first and then uses `set()` to add the document.

Comment: Cool, it works. But still the sentinel version would be much more elegant.